# Django base template view method

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-views

I' m trying to write my site with Django. I finished page and blog sides. Now i create a base.html and it has a menu. And pages title will be on the menu.

```
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    {% for page in pages %}
            <li>
             <a href="{% url 'page' page.slug %}">{{ page.title }}</a>
            </li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
```

But the question if i need pages on base template where should i call pages ? in all views methods which are use base or a common place ?

my view.py :

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse
from pages.models import Page
# Create your views here.


def mainpage(request):
    try:
        currentPage = Page.objects.get(title = "About Me")
        return render(request, 'index.html', {'mainPage' : currentPage})
    except Page.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponse('main page')

def page(request, slug):
    currentPage = get_object_or_404(Page, slug = slug)
    return render(request, 'page.html', {'currentPage' : currentPage})
    #return HttpResponse('asdsad')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Th simplest solution is to use the [template context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/api/#playing-with-context-objects):

`myapp/context_processors.py`:

```
from myapp.models import Page

def pages(request):
    return {'pages': Page.objects.all()}
```

And then add this processor to the [`TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/api/#built-in-template-context-processors) setting:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    ...
    'myapp.context_processors.pages',
)
```